# What should I use for localDataCenter in Cassandra-Driver 4.x

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-driver

When I was using `cassandra-driver` version 3.x everything worked fine. Now that I have upgraded I get the following message...

> Error: ArgumentError: 'localDataCenter' is not defined in Client options and also was not specified in constructor. At least one is required.

My client declaration looks like this...

```
const client = new Client({
        contactPoints: this.servers,
        keyspace: "keyspace",
        authProvider,
        sslOptions,
        pooling: {
            coreConnectionsPerHost: {
                [distance.local]: 1,
                [distance.remote]: 1
            }
        },
        // TODO: Needed because in spite of the documentation provided by DataStax the default value is not 0
        socketOptions: {
            readTimeout: 0
        }
});
```

What should I use for the localDataCenter property?

Answer (score 5):

To find your datacenter name, check in your node's `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file:

```
$ cat cassandra-rackdc.properties
dc=HoldYourFire
rack=force10
```

Or, run a `nodetool status`:

```
$ bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: HoldYourFire
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.0.0.1  575.64 KiB  16           ?       5c5cfc93-2e61-472e-b69b-a4fc40f94876  force10
UN  172.0.0.2  575.64 KiB  16           ?       4f040fef-5a6c-4be1-ba13-c9edbeaff6e1  force10
UN  172.0.0.3  575.64 KiB  16           ?       96626294-0ea1-4775-a08e-45661dc84cfa  force10
```

If you have multiple data centers, you should pick the same one that your application is deployed in.

Comment: I really wish I could combine your answer with GAK lol. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Since v4.0 localDataCenter is now a required Client option
When using DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, which is used by default, a local data center must now be provided to the Client options parameter as localDataCenter. This is necessary to prevent routing requests to nodes in remote data centers.

Refer upgrade guide [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.1/upgrade-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Azure CosmosDB Emulator in [Cassandra API mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#cassandra-api). I could not find any documentation on the proper `localDataCenter` property, so I just tried `datacenter1` to see what would happen.

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: ['localhost'],
  localDataCenter: 'dataCenter1',
  authProvider: new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('localhost', 'key provided during emulator startup'),
  protocolOptions: {
    port: 10350
  },
  sslOptions: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  }
});

client.connect()
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

This gave me a very helpful error message:

```
innerErrors: {
  '127.0.0.1:10350': ArgumentError: localDataCenter was configured as 'datacenter1', but only found hosts in data centers: [South Central US]
```

Once I changed my data center to "South Central US" my connection was successful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the datacenter where the application is running or the one that is close. 
Example copied from the datastax nodejs documentation

```
  const client = new cassandra.Client({ 
  contactPoints: ['host1', 'host2'],
  localDataCenter: 'datacenter1'
});
```

Comment: That really wasn't the point the point was where do I find my data center name and when I have multiple which should I use. Also why was this not an issue in 3.3?